# Drawing field shape in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to draw field shape in JavaFX.

I need to draw non-standard shape drawing by points like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0gCX.png) photo.

the photo code :
WorkingField.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import static java.lang.Math.*;


public class WorkingField extends Component {
    double L1 = 200;
    double L2 = 100;
    double L3 = 0;
    double Q11 = 0;
    double Q21 = 0;
    double Q31 = 0;
    double Q12 = 90;
    double Q22 = 90;
    double Q32 = 90;

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawLine(0,384,1366,384); // x-axis
        g.drawLine(683,0,683,1366); // y-axis

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        for(double q1=Q11;q1<=Q12;q1=q1+0.5)
        {
            for(double q2=Q21;q2<=Q22;q2=q2+0.5)
            {
                for(double q3=Q31;q3<=Q32;q3=q3+0.5)
                {
                    int X = (int) (L1*cos(q1*(3.1415926/180))+L2*cos((q1*(3.1415926/180)) + (q2*(3.1415926/180))) + L3*cos((q1*(3.1415926/180)) + (q2*(3.1415926/180)) + (q3*(3.1415926/180))));
                    int Y = (int) (L1*sin(q1*(3.1415926/180))+L2*sin((q1*(3.1415926/180)) + (q2*(3.1415926/180))) + L3*sin((q1*(3.1415926/180)) + (q2*(3.1415926/180)) + (q3*(3.1415926/180))));
                    g.drawLine(683+X,384-Y,683+X,384-Y);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WorkingField P = new WorkingField();
        JFrame F = new JFrame();
        WorkingField B = new WorkingField();
        B.setSize(100, 70);
        F.setSize(1366,768);
        F.add(P);
        F.add(B);
        F.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

But i need also to add buttons and text fields and make the user able to dragging the the axis.

what is the structure i should use and how can i draw points in it?

Comment: have you tried anything yet ? This isn't a **code request** service. Show us what **you have done**.

Comment: i don't want a code. i want know the kind of **structure** (like pane and label ..) 
the code of the attached photo isn't by JavaFX and i found it in another question.
i need to know how draw **points** to make a shape on a **certain structure** like a paper (for example) and put it in the Frame ?
Sorry for my poor English !
@Shashwat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily rewrite the above code with JavaFX if you use the Canvas class for your WorkingField class. Then you just have to pick up one of the numerous canvas examples to get the setup right.